# Partial abbreviations

Tags: vimrc, neovim

Pretty new to vim so this might be a basic question. I am trying to construct an abbreviation such that only part of a word gets corrected. For instance

```
abcPRops gets corrected to abcProps
defPRops gets corrected to defProps
<any-random-string>PRops gets corrected to  <any-random-string>Props
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match `PRops` within another string, I'm afraid this is quite complex.

The only way I'm aware of, it's the approach taken by the `IMAP` plugin that is shipped with latex-suite. The idea is to actually define mappings. Here, it would be a mapping on 's' that analyses what is before (i.e. `PRop`) to do the right thing.

The big caveat is that this approach it's extremely intrusive. Every single insert mode mapping (on printable characters) should now be registered through this plugin as it needs to keep a dictionary of contexts->replacement. (It gave me quite some troubles with my auto-pairing/bracketing plugin that I had to make compatible with IMAP when it's installed)